# Getting 404 error continuously after starting Django

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I have just started to learn Django framework version 3.2.4
I did some online lessons for last two days but suddenly started getting 404 error.
Reverted many things from settings.py and urls.py but no luck.

`Not Found: /__original-stack-frame Not Found: /__original-stack-frame [01/Jul/2021 00:25:13] "GET /__original-stack-frame?moduleId=undefined&lineNumber=undefined&columnNumber=undefined HTTP/1.1" 404 12101 [01/Jul/2021 00:25:13] "GET /__original-stack-frame?moduleId=undefined&lineNumber=undefined&columnNumber=undefined HTTP/1.1" 404 12101`

Above loops continuously and I am not able to figure out the issue.

My `urls.py` contains

```
   urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('playground/', include('playground.urls')),
    path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
]
```

And `settings.py` contains

```
 INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
# 'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'debug_toolbar',
'playground'
]
```

Can someone help?

Comment: What URL do you open in the browser? Try to remove the `__original-stack-frame` if it's there and just open the `localhost:8000`

Comment: Above error is coming in Windows console (PS or cmd) right after running server like `python manage.py runserver`

Comment: It's not a kind of "server" error, nothing breaks in your Django code. Have you tried to access the admin panel, does it work? If yes, you probably have some browser tab open with weird URL in it - just close it

Comment: Just re-installed Django in virtual environment using `pipenv  install django` . Then logged in to shell `pipenv shell` and started `python manage.py runserver` but this time also same thing is happening. It seems there is issue in environment or OS compatibility issue. I am installing this on Windows 10 Home edition.

Comment: I have restarted the machine and the error has gone. Seems something was there running along with Django, maybe some nodejs stuff. I will observe it for sometime and then close the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing running python prototype.py runserver.
The server starts OK, but it should load a page, not get 404 page not found.
The last line is executed, should result in the html display.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import re_path as url
from .views import page


urlpatterns = (
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[\w./-]+)/$', page, name='page'),
    url(r'^$', page, name='homepage'),
)
```